# PyQt, SQLAlchemy, SQLite - weird insert crash

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyqt

I'm trying to convert an xml to sqlite and get a weird error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 212, in <module> 
win = Test(a)
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 20, in __init__
self.testdb()
File "C:\Temp\xxx\scripts\xml_to_db.py", line 133, in testdb
row = connection.execute(t_id)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1405, in execute 
params)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1538, in _execute_clause
element
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1646, in _execute_context 
context)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1639, in _execute_context 
context)
File "C:\Temp\PortablePython\App\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 330, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'SELECT temperatures.id \nFROM temperatures \nWHERE temperatures.temperature = ?' ('50',)
```

where line 130 corresponds to

```
t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp)
```

Here's the whole code

```
def testdb(self):
    db_file = "C:/Temp/xxx/data/xxx/db.sqlite"

    file=QFile(db_file)
    if file.exists():
        file.remove()

    db = create_engine('sqlite:///' + db_file)
    connection = db.connect()

    metadata = MetaData()

    tb_materials = Table('materials', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('material', String)
        )

    tb_temperatures = Table('temperatures', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('temperature', String)
        )

    tb_mat_data = Table('mat_data', metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('mat_id', None, ForeignKey('materials.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
        Column('temp_id', None, ForeignKey('temperatures.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
        Column('density', String),
        Column('elasticity', String),
        Column('stress', String)
        )

    auto_assign(metadata, db)
    metadata.create_all(db)

    for m in ['SS 316']:
        data = tb_materials.insert().values(material = m)
        connection.execute(data)

    for t in ['25', '38', '50', '150']:
        data = tb_temperatures.insert().values(temperature = t)
        connection.execute(data)

    materials = ['SS 316']
    for material in materials:
        m_id = select([tb_materials.c.id], tb_materials.c.material == material)
        row = connection.execute(m_id)
        data = row.fetchone()
        m_id_key = data[0]
        temps = ['25', '38', '50', '150']
        for temp in temps:
            QMessageBox.about(self,"",temp)
            t_id = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp)
            row = connection.execute(t_id)
            data = row.fetchone()
            t_id_key = data[0]
            z = tb_mat_data.insert().values(mat_id = m_id_key, temp_id = t_id_key)
            connection.execute(z)

    connection.close()
    quit()
```

which crashes at the 3rd value of temp = '50'.

I'm totally puzzled and can't find what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what exactly is happening there, but it definitely has to do with the `Connection`. I assume there is a **bug** with something to do with the parameters not being properly cleaned up in the statement preparation before the next execution.

For example, if you replace `connection.execute(z)` with `db.execute(z)` (connectionless execution; basically using another connection), this will probably work just fine, as the statement executed in-between those (`row = connection.execute(m_id)`) has only 1 parameter.

Also if you use connectionless execution (directly calling `engine/db.execute(...)`) everywhere, all works just fine as well (as there will be new connection used for every query).

**Single SQL statement:** Apart from this issue/bug?, you can actually execute the insert on the `mat_data` in one `SQL INSERT` statement using [Correlated Update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-updates) type of query:

```
QMessageBox.about(self,"",temp)
s = select([tb_temperatures.c.id], tb_temperatures.c.temperature == temp).limit(1)
z = tb_mat_data.insert().values(mat_id = m_id_key, temp_id = s)
connection.execute(z)
```

Comment: van, That worked! As you said, it works if I do either 'db.execute(z)' instead of 'connection.execute(z)' or if I add 'limit(1) to the select. Thank you. PS. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work in this particular case while I have another 5-6 scripts converting from other 5-6 xml files all into separate databases without problems. ???

Comment: @user665327: as mentioned, i think there is a bug with the parameter clean-up either in pyodbc or in odbc. the other peace of code that is working most probably has the same number (and/or type) of parameters or has explicit commits or something like that...